# Import SQL dumps (tables) in folder from shell

Tags: mysql

Im trying to import SQL tables (actually this is files, one file for 1 table), and this is files are too big for importing in phpMyAdmin. It needs to be imported from shell. I know the command "source " to import whole DB. But I'm need to import all *.sql files in folder into one DB. Does mysql have query for this?

P.S. I can't "cat " this file because I'm getting troubles with encoding after this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a bash shell, (and for some reason you cannot con**cat** the files together) that is a simple for loop:

```
for file in *.sql; do mysql **put here your connection parameters** database_name < $file; done
```

Comment: its there a  way to not enter root password anytime?

Comment: @user60025 Yes, you can create a .my.cnf on your home directory as seen here: https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/mysql/mycnf-preference/ , use the `MYSQL_PWD` environement variable http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/password-security-user.html or the preferred and more secure method if you are using 5.6+: `mysql_config_editor` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-config-editor.html

Comment: mysql also accept the password on the command line with the -p parameter. -p'mypass'